# Single Time Login HELP

Tags: login, limit

I am developing a software on wordpress.

i want restriction on Login.

if a user login for 1st time, he should not be allowed to login 2nd time.

i am working on a software where user should not be allowed to login again to duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a user option, call it **HAS_USER_LOGGED_IN** and set the default value to *false*.  You detect this option when the user logs in. If the option is set to *false* or does not exist, then allow login to log in and set the option to *true*. Next time, if the user logs in, he/she will not be able to login, because the option is set to *true*.